# How can I detect if GHC is set to generate 32bit or 64bit code by default?

Tags: haskell, makefile, 32bit-64bit, ghc

I have the following bits in my [makefile](https://github.com/bsl/GLFW-b/blob/master/Makefile):

```
GLFW_FLAG := -m32 -O2 -Iglfw/include -Iglfw/lib -Iglfw/lib/cocoa $(CFLAGS)
...
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(GLFW_FLAG) $< -o $@
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : %.m
    $(CC) -c $(GLFW_FLAG) $< -o $@
```

The `-m32` instructs GCC to generate 32bit code.  It's there because on some configurations GHC is set to build 32bit code but GCC's default is sometimes 64bit.  I would like to generalize this so that it autodetects whether GHC is building 32bit or 64bit code and then passes the correct flag to GCC.

**Question**: How can I ask GHC what type of code (32bit vs. 64bit) it will build?

PS: My cabal file calls this makefile during the build to workaround limitations in cabal.  I do wish I could just list these as c-sources in my cabal file.

Comment: I can use this to get the word size from GHC, but I don't know if it's the right value to use: WORDSIZE  := $(shell ghc +RTS --info | ghc -e "do c <- getContents; let { r = read c :: [(String,String)]; wsize = Data.Maybe.fromJust (lookup \"Word size\" r) }; putStrLn wsize")

Comment: Is it reasonable to compile a test program and read the result with the Elf library (on hackage)?

Comment: You might be able use the result of `ghc -e 'print (maxBound :: Int)'` which should differ depending on whether you have 32bit or 64bit GHC...

Comment: `ghc --info` gives the platform information among other things (like `("Gcc Linker flags","[\"-m64\"]")`)

Comment: Can you just call ghc instead of gcc?  Then it will add the right flag automatically.

Comment: @Ed'ka, oh that looks really good.

Comment: @John L, see the "PS" comment.  I wish I could do that, but part of the problem is that some of the files are objective-c and the only GHC that will handle them correctly is not released yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Ed'ka I know the correct answer now.

The Makefile now has a rule like this:

```
GCCFLAGS  := $(shell ghc --info | ghc -e "fmap read getContents >>= putStrLn . unwords . read . Data.Maybe.fromJust . lookup \"Gcc Linker flags\"")
```

It's a bit long, but all it does is extract the "Gcc Linker flags" from ghc's output.  **Note:** This is the output of `ghc --info` and not `ghc +RTS --info`.

This is better than the other suggested ways as it gives me ***all*** the flags that need to be specified and not just the -m flag.  It's also empty when no flags are needed.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Seems you need something like `getContents >>= putStrLn . Data.Maybe.fromJust . lookup "C compiler link flags" . read`

Answer (score 6):

The usual trick I see is to ask for the size in bytes or bits of an `Int` or `Word`, since this varies in GHC based on the word size of the machine,

```
Prelude> :m + Foreign
Prelude Foreign> sizeOf (undefined :: Int)
8
Prelude Foreign> bitSize (undefined :: Int)
64
```

Or use system tools:

```
$ cat A.hs
main = print ()

$ ghc --make A.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( A.hs, A.o )
Linking A ...

$ file A
A: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), 
     dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.27, not stripped
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, it should be possible to compile a test program and read the resulting binary.

```
$ cabal install elf
```

And the code is just

```
readElf testFile'sPath >>= \e -> if elfClass e == ELFCLASS64 then print 64 else print 32
```

Or in GHCi we see:

```
> e <- readElf "/bin/ls"
> elfClass e
ELFCLASS64
```